# Print a JavaScript array to HTML, square brackets and quotation marks intact

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to set the attribute of an input form with an array of values (to use for autocomplete search). I have a JS array that looks a little something like this:

```
var suggestions = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];
```

Using jQuery, I did this:

```
$("#search-input").attr("data-source", suggestions);
```

Desired output:

```
<input type='search' data-source='["value1", "value2", "value3"]' />
```

Actual output:

```
<input type='search' data-source='value1, value2, value3' />
```

This breaks the autocomplete as it requires an array (or at least something that looks like a JavaScript array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
$("#search-input").data("source", suggestions);
```

because this

```
$("#search-input").attr("data-source", suggestions);
```

sets the *attribute value* (i.e., a string) of `data-source` to the result of `suggestions.toString()`, which of course is

```
"value1,value2,value3"
```

FWIW, this would be correct as well, even though needlessly complicated:

```
$("#search-input").attr("data-source", JSON.stringify(suggestions) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [`Split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to create array

```
 suggestions.split(",");

 'value1, value2, value3'.split(","); // ["value1", " value2", " value3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

One quick possible solution is

```
$("#search-input").attr("data-source", JSON.stringify(suggestions));
```